# Integration of Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) with Azure wiki

Tags: database, azure-devops, ssms, entity-relationship

Is there any tool or software for ER Diagram modelling that can be integrated with Azure wiki?

To be more specific i would give an example: draw.io is integrated with Confluence, so i want a software or a tool that can be integrated with Azure wiki besides mermaid since it just support a screenshot (Embed the image or link in Azure Wiki).

was looking for a third party tools such as:
Lucidchart
Draw.io
Visual Paradigm
Gliffy
Creately

or maybe there would be a way via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Comment: What do you mean about "**`Azure Wiki`**"? Where (which Azure service) is the Wiki hosted?

Comment: yup, in Azure DevOps under the project where there is a wiki for documentation

Answer (score 0):

Each Wiki page in Azure DevOps is a markdown (**`.md`**) file.

You can try to use the tool "[**Mermerd**](https://github.com/KarnerTh/mermerd?tab=readme-ov-file#mermerd)". It contains the [features](https://github.com/KarnerTh/mermerd?tab=readme-ov-file#features) to either generate plain mermaid syntax or enclose it with mermaid backticks to use directly in markdown files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But does the Wiki (markdown file) in Azure DevOps supports the ERD modelling that way?
Because I have read through their documentation that the ERD is not supported.

Also one more note: I'm just doing this as a way of documentation.

Comment: @KhaledRumman, As far as I know and based on my attempt, yes, it seems that Azure DevOps Wiki cannot well support ERD modelling. Even if for Mermaid diagrams, it also cannot well support all Mermaid diagram types. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#add-mermaid-diagrams-to-a-wiki-page).

Comment: @KhaledRumman, If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). This could make it more convenient for the engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.